# How to echo class function?

Tags: php

Is this possible to echo the class function?
I tried this but I'm getting error;

```
<input type="text" name="query">
ex. empid('1');

    <?php
    include 'class/class.sample.php';
    $sampleObj = new sample();
    $function = $_POST['query']; //ex empid('1');
    echo $drObj->$function;
    ?>
```

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: try with `echo $drObj->{$function};`

Comment: This looks great! It allows anyone to execute arbitrary methods with any arguments on that object! For example the destructor!

Comment: @arkascha thanks. meaning much better not to call value in function? all query will be just SELECT

Comment: @kimdecastro You cannot rely on any data you receive from the client side (here POST values). They might all be manipulated and forged in any way. You should never use such a value for internal execution logic, _except_ obviously as run time arguments. But to rely on the client side to name a method on an object that should be executed is a _huge_ security gap. That is especially true for `SELECT` queries, if you refer to sql queries by that. Many many programmers have fallen into that deep pit of delivering their data to strangers that way...

Comment: No I can't, since I have next to no information about what you mean by that.

Comment: @arkascha its like you query in mysql but instead you use php approach then transform it to cmd theme like. Thanks for the info it looks that it will be a huge risk using this kind of approach.

Comment: I still don't know what "transform it to cmd theme like" should mean. But I suspect that this does not really make any difference. Executing commands provided by the client _never_ is a good idea.

Comment: @arkascha "cmd theme like" you edit the design css of the result to make it look cmd(windows). thanks I appreciate every details you shared.

Comment: Ah, you mean to style the output as if it were a terminal window? Hm, what for? Why? And what are those "queries" or "commands" you want to execute? I am afraid your next step will be not to execute methods on objects, but to use php to execute commands in your system and return the result. That indeed would mean you directly hand over your system to any attacker out there. Along with a golden key. Sorry, but... don't!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can pass that just as is, but that doesn't mean it can't be achieved. You could write a small function that will parse the input into values you can use to call the desired function. Something like this

```
<?php
// I've commented your include because it doesn't benefit this example
//include 'class/class.sample.php';
$sampleObj = new sample();
//$function = $_POST['query']; //ex empid('1');

// set input hardcoded for the benefit of this example
$output = fetchFunction("empid('1','2','3')");
call_user_func_array(array($sampleObj, $output['function']), $output['parameters']);

/**
 * Use this function to parse input like "empid('1','2')"
 * to array('function'=>'empid',parameters=>array(1,2))
 * This can be used in a call_user_func_array
 *
 * @param $input
 * @return array
 */
function fetchFunction($input){
    // match inside () to get the parameters
    preg_match('/(?<=\()(.+)(?=\))/is', $input, $parameters);

    return array(
        'parameters' => explode(',', str_replace(array('\'','"'),'',$parameters[0])),
        'function' => substr($input,0,strpos($input,'('))
    );
}


class sample{
    public function empid($id){
        print_r(func_get_args());
    }
}
```

I've added a dummy class to show the output, and didn't include any check for existing functions for instance (possible with something like `method_exists`). You'll need to change that to work with your own class setup and functions.